# Сокращение кода

Tags: php, kohana

Добрый вечер.

Разбирающиеся в Kohana могут подсказать, возможно ли сократить этот код, используя values?

```
$user = ORM::factory('user_personal');

// Fill the user_personals table
$user->name     = Arr::get($_POST, 'name');
$user->email    = Arr::get($_POST, 'email');
$user->phone    = Arr::get($_POST, 'phone');
$user->b_day    = Arr::get($_POST, 'b_day');
$user->b_month  = Arr::get($_POST, 'b_month');
$user->b_year   = Arr::get($_POST, 'b_year');
$user->family   = Arr::get($_POST, 'family');
$user->town     = Arr::get($_POST, 'town');
$id = $user->save();

// Fill the user_experiences table
$user->experience->user_personal_id = $id;
$user->experience->course   = Arr::get($_POST, 'course');
$user->experience->training         = Arr::get($_POST, 'training');
$user->experience->master_class     = Arr::get($_POST, 'master_class');
$user->experience->practice         = Arr::get($_POST, 'practice');
$user->experience->other_cours      = Arr::get($_POST, 'other_cours');
$user->experience->course_ext       = Arr::get($_POST, 'course_ext');
$user->experience->save();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$user = ORM::factory('user_personal');

// Fill the user_personals table
$extracted = Arr::extract($_POST, array('name', 'email', 'phone', 'b_day', 'b_month',  'b_year', 'family', 'town'));
foreach($extracted as $parameter=>$value)
{
  $user->{$parameter} = $value;
}
```

со вторым аналогично.

а если хотите `$user->values()` использовать, то так:

```
$extracted = Arr::extract($_POST, array('name', 'email', 'phone', 'b_day', 'b_month', 'b_year', 'family', 'town')); $post = new Validation($extracted);

/** 
* Validate this array like u wanna =) 
*/

// if v.3.2 
$user->values($post->data());

// if earlier 
$user->values($post->as_array());

$user->save();
```

мог немного ошибиться, т.к. писал прям тут и по памяти.

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю как в кохане но в зенде это делается вот так

```
$formData= $this->getRequest()->getPost();
//тут обработка входящих данных 
$model->setData($formData);
$model->save();
```

думаю в кохане есть похожие методы

Comment: ага и я постом через curl че-то добавляю в POST запрос и все валится с ошибкой... Все-равно, по хорошему, нужно явно указывать какие именно данные вам нужно сохранить

Comment: В том то и дело что не валится ! индексы массива это названия полей таблицы. Если поле у таблицы обязательно not NULL тогда вывалится exeption который мы можем словить ... думаю мысль понятна !

Comment: Ну и за счет exception уменьшение кода будет незнчительным, думаю мысль понятна :D